# Гиперссылка в встроенном webBrowser

Tags: webbrowser, c++

приветствую! ) Задача следующая: в программе (на visual C++ 2008) встроен веб-браузер, он используется для вывода информации (таблиц). Я хочу вывести гиперссылку в браузер, чтобы потом можно было ее кликнуть, и выполнилась процедура в основной программе. Т.е. чтобы программа воспринила клик по ссылке, принила какие-либо значенния(свойства ссылки) и исходя из этих данных выполнилась процедура..

Comment: Вы вручную формируете html и "запихиваете" его через DocumentText?

Comment: программа генерирует таблицу и выводит его через DocumentText

Comment: впринципе, неважно, как в ручную или както программно формируется html, но выводится через DocumentText

Comment: я могу заметить событие нажатие на ссылку в веббраузере, но как я пойму что это именно конкретная ссылка

Answer (score 1):

Вообще для таких целей нужно использовать asp.net Но раз уж решили создавать веб-приложение на windows forms, то лично Я вижу только один способ реализовать Вашу задумку:

1. Формируем ссылки таким образом, что бы они могли однозначно определить какую именно функцию следует вызвать после перехода. То есть передаем некие параметры GET-запроса.
2. У WebBrowser отслеживаем событие Navigated. Из свойства "Url" этого компонента вытаскиваем тот самый параметр GET-запроса.
3. Передаем управление той или иной функции, в зависимости от значения параметра.

Сделал небольшой [проект](http://goo.gl/92vda) для Вас с примером реализации.